# spring 3.x issue of no such method error

Tags: spring, annotations

Hi i am using spring framework and while executing annotationbased test case i am getting error can any one have idea about which jar dependancy(maven artifact) file do i need to add in my pom.xml ?

org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAttribute.getQualifier() no such method error

Comment: Could you please post the stack trace - I can not scroll that window ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have two incompatible jars.

Check that: `spring-tx` and `spring-test` is of the same version (3.0.x).

If this does not help. Place a break point at `TransactionalTestExecutionListener` and check that the concreate class that implements `TransactionAttribute` is of correct version too.